# Trying to input IPs to an Automated script so I can scan them

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code I am working on for my thesis, I need to input multiple IPs to a command and execute it in Linux this is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
B=[]
a=np.genfromtxt('text.txt',skip_header=5)
list1 = a.tolist()
for i in range(len(list1)):
    B.append(str(list1[i][0]))
f= open("IP.txt","w+")
for i in B:
    f.write(f"{i}\n")
with open('IP.txt',"r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1]
for i in range (len(B)):
    with open("IP.txt","r") as f:
        d=str(i)
        bashCommand = ("bash ./nmapAutomator {} >> results"+d+".txt")
        print (bashCommand.format(f.readlines()[i]))
```

The file I want to read from has this form:

```
 Currently scanning: (passive)   |   Screen View: Unique Hosts
 10 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 4 hosts.   Total size: 600
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address     Count     Len  MAC Vendor / Hostname      
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 192.168.1.201   00:0c:29:a2:56:2b      5     300  VMware, Inc.
 192.168.1.1     00:11:22:33:44:55      2     120  Router Manufacturer
 192.168.1.200   00:0c:29:3a:cb:5b      1      60  VMware, Inc.
```

If I were to replace the IP's with numbers, the program works great and I get the commands printed back like this : ./nmapAutomator 192.168.1.201... etc ... However with the IPs not being numbers I get the NaN error...
Is there any workaround on this? Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Why in the world are you using numpy for this??

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IPs using a regular expression:

```
"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
```

Working example:

```
my_string = """ Currently scanning: (passive)   |   Screen View: Unique Hosts
 10 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 4 hosts.   Total size: 600
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address     Count     Len  MAC Vendor / Hostname      
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 192.168.1.201   00:0c:29:a2:56:2b      5     300  VMware, Inc.
 192.168.1.1     00:11:22:33:44:55      2     120  Router Manufacturer
 192.168.1.200   00:0c:29:3a:cb:5b      1      60  VMware, Inc."""


import re
results = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", my_string)

# results:
# ['192.168.1.201', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.200']
```

Comment: And is there a simple way to convert .txt file to string? All ways I found seem to return a blank list when I try to print it.. Thanks again!

Comment: use f.read() instead of f.readlines()